# Python 3.10 for loop print performance

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I have a dictionary object that generates a new dictionary based on a method called `buildDatabaseItem`:

```
item = {
    "gid": "00A00D0C-B0CD-0000-00C0-000000B0E0C0",
    "A_Field": "97",
    "B_Field": "956",
    "C_Field": 15.90,
    "D_Field": 15.00,
    "E_Field": "Andrew",
    "F_Field": "Very important Field",
    "G_Field": None,
    "H_Field": "2018-02-08",
    "I_Field": 1,
    "J_Field": 0,
    "K_Field": "back",
    "L_Field": 6,
    "M_Field": 0,
    "N_Field": None,
    "O_Field": "1",
    "P_Field": "2.2",
    "Q_Field": None,
    "R_Field": None,
    "S_Field": None,
    "T_Field": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
}

def buildDatabaseItem(_item):
    return {
        "gid": _item['gid'],
        "A_Field": str(_item['A_Field']),
        "B_Field": str(_item['B_Field']),
        "C_Field": str(_item['C_Field']),
        "D_Field": str(_item['D_Field']),
        "E_Field": str(_item['E_Field']),
        "F_Field": str(_item['F_Field']),
        "G_Field": str(_item['G_Field']),
        "H_Field": str(_item['H_Field']),
        "I_Field": str(_item['I_Field']),
        "J_Field": str(_item['J_Field']),
        "K_Field": str(_item['K_Field']),
        "L_Field": str(_item['L_Field']),
        "M_Field": str(_item['M_Field']),
        "N_Field": str(_item['N_Field']),
        "O_Field": str(_item['O_Field']),
        "P_Field": str(_item['P_Field']),
        "Q_Field": str(_item['Q_Field']),
        "R_Field": str(_item['R_Field']),
        "S_Field": str(_item['S_Field']),
        "T_Field": _item['T_Field'] or '',
        "New_A_Field": get_new_field_a(_item),
        "New_B_Field": get_new_field_b(_item),
        "New_C_Field": get_new_field_c(_item),
    }


def get_new_field_a(_item):
    return 9 * 13


def get_new_field_b(_item):
    return {'first': 4, 'second': 5}


def get_new_field_c(_item):
    return {'firstly': 'one', 'secondly': 'two'}
```

if i iterate 10.000 times for the same object and build/print inside the loop statement:

```
start_time = time.time()

for i in range(10_000):
    temp = buildDatabaseItem(item)
    print(temp)

end_time = time.time()
print(f"Total time elapsed: {end_time - start_time}seconds")
```

**I've got the following output**

```
Total time elapsed: 2.675130844116211 seconds
```

but if i append all new objects to a list and then iterate and print:

```
start_time = time.time()

items = []

for i in range(10_000):
    temp = buildDatabaseItem(item)
    items.append(temp)

for _i in items:
    print(_i)

end_time = time.time()
print(f"Total time elapsed with a List: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
```

**I've got the following output**

```
Total time elapsed with List: 0.41146302223205566 seconds
```

**And if i increase the loop to 100.000**

```
Total time elapsed: 23.59450387954712 seconds
Total time elapsed with a List: 2.6670145988464355 seconds
```

**Why is there a significant disparity in performance?**

Comment: In general, no one care about optimizing printing because this is mostly used for debugging purpose and debugging do not need to be very fast, but only fast enough. If your application bottleneck is printing, then there is definitively something wrong in your process. Printing on Windows is very slow because it performs a (30 year old) MS-DOS emulation under the hood which is extremely slow. Besides Printing is often slow because of buffer flushing. Flushs are not needed unless you plan to read this massive amount of data in real time which make no sense to me...

Comment: Thank you for you time Jerome. My question is not for debugging print but why printing inside the first loop makes so much slower the total process. In both cases two operations performed. Create an object and print it versus creating all objects and print them separately. Shouldn’t be the time same for both operations ?

Comment: It depends of the terminal and how data is flushed, synchronized, etc. I *cannot reproduce* the problem on my machine on Windows using CPython 3.8.1 (in a IPython cmd). The two versions are about equally fast (1% difference). The first run is a bit slower (possibly due to frequency scaling, caching, conditional predictions, etc.).

Comment: I thought that something under the hood was reducing performance. 
Have you tried with my code including object creation? Because I have seen the behavior you describe using only print method.

Comment: I just copy pasted your 3 blocks of code, twice, and retrieved the timing (ie. indicated by "Total time elapsed with a List") for the second run. Nothing more.